# Paired t test-like solution in a two-group pretest/posttest design

Tags: t-test, repeated-measures, interpretation, ancova, pre-post-comparison

I am analyzing a dataset where pre/post measurements are made (before/after a surgery) on patients who can belong to two groups, and we are interested in how group membership - let's call it G - affects the impact of the surgery. (It is a nonrandomized observational study, but let's put other confounders aside now for simplicity.)

I am no expert in such situations, so I read a bit, and it seems that percentage change is a [bad idea](http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/Main/MeasureChange). As this is not a randomized trial, it is also not a question that we can not neglect the baseline measurement. Thus, we are left with two options:

```
lm( I(Post-Pre) ~ G, data = RawData )

(Intercept)            G  
   -0.02563      1.04204
```

i.e. change score, or

```
lm( Post ~ Pre + G, data = RawData )

(Intercept)          Pre            G  
  -0.003125     0.006014     0.973866
```

i.e. baseline adjusted as a covariate. (That is, ANCOVA, if I am not mistaken with the terminology.)

What do they mean, and how they are related to each other is discussed in the literature in great detail. My understanding is that generally speaking the latter [is the](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/sim.2682/full) better [approach](http://www.fharrell.com/2017/04/statistical-errors-in-medical-literature.html#change). Hope I am right up to this point.

Now, what I don't understand is how paired $t$ test fits into this picture. That is, how

```
lme( Meas ~ PrePost * G, random = ~1|id,
          data = reshape( RawData, varying = c( "Pre", "Post" ), v.names = "Meas",
          timevar = "PrePost", direction = "long" ) )

(Intercept)     PrePost           G   PrePost:G 
 0.02264409 -0.02563254 -0.06858446  1.04203755 

Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 | id
        (Intercept) Residual
StdDev:   0.0802519 1.034537
```

relates to the above procedures...?
(I called it "paired $t$ test-ish" because `lme( Meas ~ PrePost, random = ~1|id )` would have been equivalent to the usual paired $t$-test, with no group membership.)

I don't think that it is equivalent to any of the above approaches, and it might be completely pointless (I have the feeling that it measures something different), but I simply don't see what it means...

(The above examples pertain to `set.seed( 1 )` and `RawData <- data.frame( Pre = rnorm( 1000 ), Post = rep( 0:1, each = 500 ) + rnorm( 1000 ), G = rep( 0:1, each = 500 ), id = 1:1000 )`.)

Comment: +1. Would you post the output of all three options so that we could see how different/similar they are?

Comment: @amoeba: Sure! (Although I intended the code only as a clear demonstration of the concept, not as a concrete numerical example.) But now I extended it.

Comment: I don't really know R but I suspect that there is something wrong with your `lme` call or perhaps with the `reshape` inside it. The output does not make sense.

Comment: @amoeba: Why do you think it doesn't make sense? It just reports an intercept and the coefficients for the two right hand side variables (just as in the ANCOVA case).

Comment: Well, because the coefficient for `G` should be around 1, and for `PrePost` should be around 0.

Comment: @amoeba : Ah, I see! You're right, I've given a silly specification, not the one I intended to. What I've written implies that the effect of `G` is the same both before and after the surgery, as I forget to add an interaction between `G` and `PrePost`. I edited the code, and now the results are also what you expect (I hope at least).

Comment: That makes sense! But now I am not sure what you are asking. You have three related ways to analyze the data, and on your toy dataset all three give very similar results. Are you asking if there are subtle difference between these three approaches?

Comment: @amoeba : Broadly speaking: what are the pros/cons of these three approaches? When should we use them (even if just "generally speaking")...? I understand that change score is typically not a good idea, so the question rather pertains to the ANCOVA approach vs. mixed-effects approach. More specifically: how are these methods related, is there any mathematical connection between them? Again, not between ANCOVA and change score, because I know that they're extensively compared in the literature, but between these methods and the mixed-effects approach.

Comment: @TamasFerenci The mixed effect model is not the right approach because you have the pre-assessments as a function of the pre/post assignment, which they are not. Also have you read over [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3466/best-practice-when-analysing-pre-post-treatment-control-designs)?

Answer (score 3):

The paired t-test is best applied to a crossover study so that
order effects can cancel out.  For observational pre-post comparisons the design is very weak.

The ANCOVA on the raw response is preferred because the slope on pre might not be 1.0 and the difference post-pre may not be ordinal if post and pre are ordinal but not interval scaled.   Ordinal regression is a  general solution, and must be done on raw values.

Your ANCOVA example is comparing 2 independent groups but the paired t is testing a completely different within-group hypothesis.  I'm not as clear on the random effects model.  You'll see old discussions of this in the statistics literature under the phrase "recovery of intra-block
information".

Comment: Thank you! I think here lies the key: "Your ANCOVA example is comparing 2 independent groups but the paired t is testing a completely different within-group hypothesis" Could you please elaborate this a bit...?
Right now I believe that the 3. option (paired t test like, random effects) is an extension of the change scores approach - check the coefficients! - so they're very strongly related, but I can't prove it...

Comment: I was just referring to the case where the dataset contains one row per subject and there is a grouping variable.  Then the grouping variable contrasts two independent groups of subjects.

Answer (score 1):

I think the complaints brought up by the Vanderbilt site are valid ones, but they can't be applied universally without knowledge of the *question*. They mention specific graphical tests which can be used to assess assumptions about a magnitude of effect. For instance, in HIV rebound patients, administration of antiretroviral therapy (ART) has a demonstrable geometric mean effect. That's because when the virus is more prolific, the PK dynamics are such that the virus interacts at a higher rate with the ART. Issues with interpretation behoove us to think more carefully about our interpretation than to seek in vain an omnibus that permits us to be loose with interpretation.

You bring up two separate points: ANCOVA vs paired differences and percent change as the scale of effect. Modeling change as a percentage involves performing a log transform of the outcome, re-exponentiating the coefficients obtained from the linear model, and interpreting them as a percentage change. A paired t-test is a special case of a linear model without log-transform where you actually model an offset:

\begin{equation}
E[Y_1 | Y_0, X] = \beta_0 + Y_0 + \beta_1 X
\end{equation}

$\beta_1$ is the intervention effect as a mean difference obtained from a paired t-test, or a univariate t-test based on pairwise differences in $Y_1, Y_0$. Note the term $Y_0$ does *not* have a coefficient.

The ANCOVA is seen as a better model because it is a more flexible parametric model which incorporates a coefficient for the referent/baseline term.

\begin{equation}
E[Y_1 | Y_0, X] = \beta_0 + \gamma Y_0 + \beta_1 X
\end{equation}

$\beta_1$ still has the same interpretation: the expected difference in outcome comparing individuals who receive the intervention to those who don't *conditional* upon baseline/referent value.

To model percent change in an ANCOVA design, you apply log transform of the outcome.

\begin{equation}
E[\log Y_1 | Y_0, X] = \beta_0 + \gamma Y_0 + \beta_1 X
\end{equation}

And $\exp(\beta_1)$ is interpreted as a percent difference in outcome comparing those who receive intervention to those who don't conditional on their baseline/referent value.

The issue of homogeneity which is addressed in the Vanderbilt site is also worth mention. Suppose you are interested in modeling percent change as with our final log transformed ANCOVA model. Suppose further, there is a truncation of treatment effect for a range of values, like with our HIV patients receiving ARTs. If the viral load drops below a threshold the devices cannot detect its presence. In many data analyses, analysts impute the minimum (a pragmatic and inefficient solution). This would, by assumption, violate the predicted trend. However, we can view the model as summarizing those data in spite of those differences, or any other subgroup differences, when we interpret the $\beta_1$ or $\exp \beta_1$ as the Average Causal Effect (or ACE). This is an issue of interpretation that considers the whole population rather than what individual outcomes are, which is often a follow-up question requiring much more extensive design and investigation.

The mixed model is a bit confusing since you haven't defined terms. Nonetheless, a mixed approach is the way to go if there are more than one post measurement. Why would you assess more than one post measurement? Measurement error: blood pressure? different every day, viral load? different every day, weight? you get the picture. By design if an outcome can be measured cheaply but has low reliability, an efficient design might specify multiple measurements as a way of reducing intraindividual variability. However, in doing this, we now have correlated measures. Introducing a random intercept further reduces intraindividual variability, and hence the overall variability of the effect estimate, by inducing an exchangeable correlation structure where each repeated measure within an individual has a fixed, constant, positive correlation. This design feature updates ANCOVA to be a "repeated measures ANCOVA".

As a note your R notation is wrong. Note in my describing the above design: we incorporate a baseline measure as a *covariate* in the ANCOVA design or an *offset* in the paired design. In your `reshape` dataset, the pre and post measures are taken as exogenous measures which are predicted by `G` which I presume is the intervention design. Baseline measures are *NOT* predicted by this value, so that model is wrong. "Repeated measures" in a pre-post design means you have *more than one* measure of the outcome.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I'm still trying to understand every part, in the meantime let me reflect on two remarks: "The mixed model is a bit confusing since you haven't defined terms. Nonetheless, a mixed approach is the way to go if there are more than one post measurement." No! We have exactly one measurement before, and one after. The reason why I used random effects model is purely syntactical: I took the example of the paired t test, and I "mechanically" extended it with a covariate (G).

Comment: "or an offset in the paired design" Okay, I understand this solution, but my question still stands: what happens if you do it the way I did...? (Please note that I edited this part, the original was not what I intended, sorry!) Does it have a meaning? If so, what? What does it test? How is it related to the previous examples?

Comment: "In your reshape dataset, the pre and post measures are taken as exogenous measures which are predicted by G which I presume is the intervention design. Baseline measures are NOT predicted by this value, so that model is wrong." I'm not perfectly sure that I understood you, however: why is this necessarily wrong? This was not a randomized trial, rather an observation, so baselines may very well be different between groups! I.e. I can predict even the baseline value with `G`.

Comment: @TamasFerenci what is "mechanical extension" of a paired t-test? Do you mean that you regressed "pre" as a covariate and "g" as a group indicator on "post" as an outcome in a linear model and conducted inference on g?

Comment: @TamasFerenci can you explain the nature of the "group"? Is this an exposure (a term I'll use here on)? Were participants exposed *before* the "pre" measurement was taken? I presume not, since it would not be a pre-post design otherwise. If not, is the "exposure" value coded to 0 for *all* rows in which the outcome is a pre-measurement and coded to 1 only for the rows where the individual is exposed?

Comment: "what is "mechanical extension" of a paired t-test?" I just wanted to indicate that the usual paired t-test is `lme( Meas ~ PrePost , random = ~1|id)` and all I did was to incorporate the group by adding it as a predictor variable. (And I was unsure whether it is meaningful at all, or not.) "Do you mean that you regressed "pre" as a covariate and "g" as a group indicator on "post" as an outcome in a linear model and conducted inference on g?" No! See the code! I regressed the measurements as outcome with group membership and whether it was pre or post as predictors (with interaction).

Comment: "can you explain the nature of the "group"?" Sure! It is a characteristic of the patient. (In my original example: whether it is his/her first surgery or revision.) But I can image that it might be sex, presence of a comorbidity etc. "Were participants exposed before the "pre" measurement was taken?" Yes, they were! Even sex is a possible example. "I presume not, since it would not be a pre-post design otherwise." Well, it might be a terminological confusion then... By pre/post I meant that we are interested in how the surgery affects patients from different groups.

Comment: @TamasFerenci if the experimental condition or pseudoexperimental condition is not one which is modified between a "baseline" and "followup" measurement, then you do not have a pre/post design. It is simply a repeated measures analysis. Here, aside from endogenous temporal trends, the observations are exchangeable. Pre/post designs do not have such an attribute.

Comment: Well, it's entirely possible that my terminology is wrong! Here everyone underwent the same intervention (a surgery), they were measured before and after it, and we are interested in how the characteristics of the patient (eg. sex, whether the surgery was primary or revision) influences the change in the measured parameter.

Comment: @TamasFerenci then *this* is a pre-post model. You model change from baseline to follow-up. Everything in my answer is relevant and should be reviewed and considered for your question. Your reshape dataset is not correct unless you adjust for a time-varying covariate of pre-post indicator and its interactions with other factors. That approach is highly criticized as a longitudinal data analysis approach though.

Comment: Thank you! I'll think this one over once more. In the meantime, may I ask you if you'd give me some literature reference to substantiate these? So that I can cite it in a paper.